# call method when phone is shaken

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have created a windows phone app that locates a users location when a button is pressed but I want to do away with the button and make this function occur when the phone is shaken! Below is the code that I have created so far, when the application loads it will call a function called **Locate_Me** which initializes the Accelerometer.

```
private async void Locate_Me()
    {

        if (accelerometer == null)
        {
            // Instantiate the Accelerometer.
            accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
            accelerometer.TimeBetweenUpdates = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20);
            accelerometer.CurrentValueChanged +=
                new EventHandler<SensorReadingEventArgs<AccelerometerReading>>(accelerometer_CurrentValueChanged);
        }

        try
        {
            statusTextBlock.Text = "starting accelerometer.";
            accelerometer.Start();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            statusTextBlock.Text = "unable to start accelerometer.";
        } 
}
```

So how would I go about making the onShaken function?

Answer (score 1):

First step: Download ShakeGestures library from microsoft site [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=219094). Add ShakeGetures.dll to your project. 
Now it's a piece of cake for you to detect shake gestures. Below is the code you can use:

```
 //constructor of page register event handler for shake
 public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
            // register shake event
        ShakeGesturesHelper.Instance.ShakeGesture +=new 
           EventHandler<ShakeGestureEventArgs>(Instance_ShakeGesture);

            // optional, set parameters
            ShakeGesturesHelper.Instance.MinimumRequiredMovesForShake = 2;

            // start shake detection
            ShakeGesturesHelper.Instance.Active = true;
    }
    private void Instance_ShakeGesture(object sender, ShakeGestureEventArgs e)
    {
      //call your method
    }
```

This is the minimal code you would require. Worked for me.